# Qr and bar code scanner doesn't support portrait mode

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code

I downloaded the project for qr and bar code scanner from git hub and facing difficulty in changing scanner from landscape mode to portrait mode and i checked many stackoverflow links but didn't get proper solution and i am using zxing 2.1 jar in my code.Here is my code please check the code and  please do some helpful to solve this problem.Thanks in advance!!
Error:**"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crop rectangle does not fit within image data."**

//BarcodeReader

```
package com.dynamsoft.barcodereader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

 public class BarcodeReader extends Activity {
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private CameraManager mCameraManager;
    private HoverView mHoverView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        mHoverView = (HoverView)findViewById(R.id.hover_view);
        mHoverView.update(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());

        mCameraManager = new CameraManager(this);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCameraManager.getCamera());
        mPreview.setArea(mHoverView.getHoverLeft(),     mHoverView.getHoverTop(), mHoverView.getHoverAreaWidth(), display.getWidth());
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        getActionBar().hide();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mPreview.onPause();
        mCameraManager.onPause(); 
    }

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mCameraManager.onResume();
        mPreview.setCamera(mCameraManager.getCamera());
    }
}
```

//CameraManager .java

```
package com.dynamsoft.barcodereader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraManager {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Context mContext;

    public CameraManager(Context context) {
         mContext = context;
        // Create an instance of Camera

         mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    }

    public Camera getCamera() {
        return mCamera;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void onPause() {
        releaseCamera();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        }

        Toast.makeText(
                mContext,
                "preview size = "
                        + mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width +     ", "
                        + mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    private static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
       }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

}
```

//HoverView .java

```
package com.dynamsoft.barcodereader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class HoverView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private int mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom;

    public HoverView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    public void update(int width, int height) {
        int centerX = width / 2;
        int centerY = height / 2;
        mLeft = centerX - 200;
        mRight = centerX + 200;
        mTop = centerY - 200;
        mBottom = centerY + 200;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getHoverLeft() {
        return mLeft;
    }

    public int getHoverTop() {
        return mTop;
    }

    public int getHoverAreaWidth() {
        return mRight - mLeft;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom, mPaint);
    }
}
```

//CameraPreview.java

```
package com.dynamsoft.barcodereader;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.PlanarYUVLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private static final String TAG = "camera";
    private int mWidth, mHeight;
    private Context mContext;
    private MultiFormatReader mMultiFormatReader;
    private AlertDialog mDialog;
    private int mLeft, mTop, mAreaWidth, mAreaHeight;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mContext = context;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    mWidth = 640;
    mHeight = 480;

    params.setPreviewSize(mWidth, mHeight);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    mMultiFormatReader = new MultiFormatReader();

    mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(mPreviewCallback);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;
}

public void onPause() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }
}

private Camera.PreviewCallback mPreviewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (mDialog.isShowing())
            return;

        LuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, mWidth,
                mHeight, mLeft, mTop, mAreaWidth, mAreaHeight, false);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Result result;

        try {
            result = mMultiFormatReader.decode(bitmap, null);
            if (result != null) {
                mDialog.setTitle("Result");
                mDialog.setMessage(result.getText());
                mDialog.show();
            }
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

public void setArea(int left, int top, int areaWidth, int width) {
    double ratio = width / mWidth;
    mLeft = (int) (left / (ratio + 1));
    mTop = (int) (top / (ratio + 1));
    mAreaHeight = mAreaWidth = mWidth - mLeft * 2;
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It does not work on portrait mode. You need to limit your barcode activity to landscape mode.

```
<activity
        android:name=".BarcodeReader"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```